# Getting odd values in ArcGIS attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4

I'm very new to/teaching myself ArcGIS.

The goal:  extract raster data using multi values to point

The process:  In short, I overlaid lat/long coordinate data on top of a raster, and used the Spatial Analyst tool to extract the values from those points.  The raster contains data related to percent wet nitrogen deposition, so the values should be between 0 - 100.  Prior to overlaying the coordinates on the raster data, I changed the raster datum to NAD83, to match the coordinate datum. I also changed the projection to match as well.

The issue:  Many of the cells in the resulting attribute table contain this value: "-3.40282E+38".  What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

That (`-3.40282E+38`) is likely a `NODATA` value used in rasters, which is used to indicate the data/variable of interest is not available at the cell. Often times, people use impossible values like `-3.40282E+38`, `-9999` depending on the type and domain of pixels.